# What is a good book reference on the definition of "subharmonic frequency"?

Tags: reference-request

Is there a good book reference on the definition of "subharmonic frequency" as integer fractions of the highest available frequency?

Comment: There are a few here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subharmonic#References

Comment: Well, they are music and acoustic books, but I need a mathematical, or electrical engineering, or DSP area book reference.

Answer (score 1):

"Highest available frequency" sounds fishy but here's a reference from dynamics:

[image: Book clip]

Cunningham, Walter Jack. *Introduction to Nonlinear Analysis*. 1st ed. New York, USA: McGraw-Hill, 1958, pp. 191–192.

ISBN 10: 0070149178  ISBN 13: 9780070149175